# How to start only SmallTest in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, androidx, androidx-test

I've started a new Project with testautomation. Some tests take some time These have been marked as @LargeTest. There are also some SmallTests (unit tests). The developers need to run the small tests more often.

I have searched through the web some time and saw how to run the tests by size via adb shell and gradle. But nowhere there was a solution directly in AndroidStudio

I have some Classes like this of this kind and some simple Core logic tests:

```java
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

@LargeTest
public class ExampleActivityTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Do setup
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // reset changes
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeFancyStuff()  {
       // Test comes here
    }
}
```

Some times only the Small and/or medium tests need to be executed. How to do this in Android Studio?